# Closing cursors across JAR boundaries

Tags: android, cursor, android-contentprovider, memory-leaks

I use a content provider/resolver, have a separate project/lib that provides a number of DB helper methods. I have a second project/lib that does handy things with a cursor.

Imagine as such DB Helper Method (com.example.DBHelper):

```
    public String[] dumpColumnTable() {
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(MY_URI, 
                new String[] { FIELD }, 
                null,                   
                null,                   
                null                    
                );
        return UtilMethods.createArrayFromCursor(cursor);
}
```

Then the Util methods (com.example.UtilMethods):

```
public static String[] createArrayFromCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    return createArrayFromCursor(cursor, 0);
}

public static String[] createArrayFromCursor(Cursor cursor, int column) {
    if (cursor == null) return null;
    String[] strings = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int i=0;
        do {
            strings[i] = cursor.getString(column);    
            i++;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return strings;
}
```

Obviously the cursor isn't closed. This will leak a cursor. Logcat will give you that message.

SO, close it in the inner util function:

```
public static String[] createArrayFromCursor(Cursor cursor, int column) {
    if (cursor == null) return null;
    String[] strings = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int i=0;
        do {
            strings[i] = cursor.getString(column);    
            i++;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return strings;
}
```

But logcat will still claim the cursor wasn't closed before finalize.

If instead, in the DB Helper method, I save the return value, close the cursor, then return it, I get no cursor leak/logcat message:

```
public String[] dumpColumnTable() {
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(MY_URI, 
                new String[] { FIELD }, 
                null,                   
                null,                   
                null                    
                );
        String[] toret =  UtilMethods.createArrayFromCursor(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return toret;
}
```

Why ? In debugging, the cursor is marked as close when the calls return. The call stack goes from my activity->db helper->util methods. The db helper and util methods are in separate projects from the activity.

Is there some pass by reference/value issue I'm missing, or crossing multiple JAR boundaries, or the casting of what is a SQLiteCursor to the generic Cursor type that I'm missing ?